# When continuously deploying to staging, what happens when you swap staging and production deployment slots?

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

We are creating a system in Azure whereby we set up continuous deployment from a Git branch to a staging slot. When we are ready to deploy to production, we will swap the staging slot with the deployment slot (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots).

```
+-------------------------------------+    +------------------------+
|GIT                                  |    |AZURE                   |
|                                     |    |                        |
|   master                            |    |                        |
|     +                               |    |                        |
|     |                               |    |                        |
|     | 1. merge into staging-branch  |    |                        |
|     |                               |    |                        |
|     v                               |    |                        |
|   staging-branch  +-----------------+----+> Staging slot          |
|                    2. Continuous deployment     ^                 |
+----------------------------^--------+    |      |                 |
                             |             |      |  3. Swap slots  |
                             |             |      |  3a. Swap again if something
                             +             |      |      went wrong |
                   Question: When does     |      v                 |
                   this re-deploy?         |  Deployment slot       |
                                           |                        |
                                           +------------------------+
```

My question is what happens to the staging slot after the swap? The desired behaviour is that nothing happens so that a re-swap to roll back to a stable state is possible. However, I am concerned that the continuous deployment system might realise there is a change and immediately re-deploy from `staging-branch`.

My guess is that there will be no re-deployment until either 1) another commit is pushed to `staging-branch` or 2) the re-deployment is kicked off manually. However, I haven't seen this documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The continuous deployment part is just looking at changes in your repo, not changes in the actual content of the web app. When you swap, the staging slot will now contain the previous version of production, until you commit changes to your repo, which will then be pushed and overwrite it.